# How to handle post request in python

Tags: python, post, request

how can I handle post request in python script? Somewhere I want to send it from ajax to the python script with given params. What's correct way to handle that data in python?

Comment: Impossible to answer this question without more details. What is your 'python script'? How is it running on the server? Is it a standalone CGI, is it Django or another framework, or what?

Comment: @daniel-roseman
I have my standalone computer with single python script. I have html with jquery library. There I call ajax method with script name as my python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably use a cgi and you can handle it with form = cgi.FieldStorage() as described into  http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html